# Julia parsing float from file: type woes

Tags: julia

This is the line in my file I want to read into Julia:

`O1 O 0.00351(19) 0.66716(19) -0.36485(16)`

I want to replace the parenthesis and read these as floats. I think that this should work, but it does not.

```
lines = readlines(open("myfile"))
line = lines[1]

frac_coords = split(line)[3:end]
i = 1
frac_coords[i] = replace(frac_coords[i], "(", "")

frac_coords[i] = replace(frac_coords[i], ")", "")

frac_coords[i] = parse(Float64, frac_coords[i])
```

I get the error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{SubString{ASCIIString}}, ::Float64)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor SubString{ASCIIString}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T<:AbstractString}(::Type{SubString{T<:AbstractString}}, !Matched::T<:AbstractString)
  convert{T<:AbstractString,S<:Union{Char,Int32,UInt32}}(::Type{T<:AbstractString}, !Matched::AbstractArray{S<:Union{Char,Int32,UInt32},1})
  ...

 while loading In[53], in expression starting on line 14

 in setindex! at array.jl:313
```

and I have tried doing conversions to AbstractStrings. and in the beginning `convert(Array{ASCIIString}, split(line)[3:end])`.

Shouldn't this be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` function returns an array of `ASCIIString` so, `frac_coords` will become a variable of that type:

```
frac_coords = split(line)[3:end]
typeof(frac_coords) # =>  Array{SubString{ASCIIString},1}
```

and any try to change it's elements types will results an exception:

`frac_coords[1]=0 # => Error`

So, why don't simply use different variables of right types?

```
floats=Array(Float64,length(frac_coords))
floats[i] = parse(Float64, frac_coords[i])
```

**EDIT** or use an `Vector{Any}()` as a container for both types:

```
frac_coords=Vector{Any}()
push!(frac_coords,split(line)[3:end]...)
for i=1:length(frac_coords)
   frac_coords[i]=replace(replace(frac_coords[i], "(", ""),")", "")
   frac_coords[i]=parse(Float64,frac_coords[i])
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I still don't think it is that intuitive. `x=1.0` and then `x=1` converts from Float64 to Int. I guess that would involve mixed types in the array though. Still, it could change to an Array{T} where T is a union of the two types right?

Comment: @Cokes, definitely yes, many possible solutions exist, e.g. as you already mentioned it's possible to use a more general container, like a vector of `Union`s or a vector of `Any`, type.